# " ion-raw " is not a known element

Tags: android, angular, cordova, ionic-framework, apk

i have created mobile application with ionic framewrok and angular js when i compile with
ionic serve and ionic lab
it works well but when i tried to get apk using
ionic cordova build android --release --prod

following error happens.

[image: error1]

here is my ionic info
[image: ionic info].

i have tried several troubleshhoting methods but couldn't resolve it. here is my code

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-title>
      LIVE-STATISCS
    </ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>


<ion-content>
  
        <ion-grid>
          <div class="ion-padding">
          <ion-raw><ion-col >UPDATE-TIME</ion-col><ion-col><p style="background:#99FFCC" *ngIf="!error;else errorContent">{{ TotSL3? TotSL3 : '-' }}</p></ion-col></ion-raw>
          <ion-raw><ion-col>NEW-CASES</ion-col><ion-col><p style="background:#99FFCC"*ngIf="!error;else errorContent">{{ TotSL? TotSL : '-' }}</p></ion-col></ion-raw> 
          <ion-raw><ion-col>TOTAL-CASES</ion-col><ion-col><p style="background:#99FFCC"*ngIf="!error;else errorContent">{{ TotSL2? TotSL2 : '-' }}</p></ion-col></ion-raw>
          <ion-raw><ion-col>LOCAL-DEATHS</ion-col><ion-col><p style="background:#99FFCC"*ngIf="!error;else errorContent">{{ TotSL4? TotSL4 : '-' }}</p> </ion-col></ion-raw>
          <ion-raw><ion-col>NEW-DEATHS</ion-col><ion-col></ion-col><p style="background:#99FFCC"*ngIf="!error;else errorContent">{{ TotSL5? TotSL5 : '-' }}</p></ion-raw>
          <ng-template #errorContent><p><span style="color: red;">{{error}}</span></p></ng-template>
        </div>
        </ion-grid>
  
  <ion-button [routerLink]="['/fist-page']"expand="full" fill="outline">BACK</ion-button>

</ion-content>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change it to `ion-row`, that might solve the compilation error.

Please refer to the doc: https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/row